# How can I count operations in makefile for loop and take action on certain count values?

Tags: android, makefile

The main [AOSP](http://source.android.com/) makefile prints a lot of "including file ..." lines. I wanted to trim that down a bit and only print every 10 or 100 includes.

The original line from `build/core/main.mk`:

```
$(foreach mk, $(subdir_makefiles), $(info including $(mk) ...)$(eval include $(mk)))
```

I want to print the including... line less often.

Answer (score 0):

This code uses the shell and eval functions to update a count. It then does simple pattern matching looking for any numbers ending in 00.

```
define count_includes
    $(eval INCLUDE_COUNT := $(shell echo "$$(( $(INCLUDE_COUNT) + 1 ))" ) ) \
    $(if $(patsubst %00,,$(INCLUDE_COUNT)),,$(info $(INCLUDE_COUNT): including $(1) ...) )
endef

$(foreach mk, $(subdir_makefiles), $(call count_includes, $(mk))$(eval include $(mk)))
```

Note: I don't bother to initialize `INCLUDE_COUNT` above, because it starts out empty/undefined and `$(( + 1 ))` evaluates to `1`.

I ran a couple tests with the original code, this code, and all printing removed. All times on my machine were within 1 second of 35 seconds. So, no real performance loss.

Here's the makefile I used for testing:

```
define count_includes
    $(eval INCLUDE_COUNT := $(shell echo "$$(( $(INCLUDE_COUNT) + 1 ))" ) ) \
    $(if $(patsubst %00,,$(INCLUDE_COUNT)),,$(info $(INCLUDE_COUNT): including $(1) ...) )
endef

FILELIST := $(wildcard /usr/share/man/man1/*)
$(foreach mk, $(FILELIST), $(call count_includes, $(mk)))

.PHONY: all
all:
    @echo "All done." $(INCLUDE_COUNT)
```

If I wanted intervals other than pattern matching on 0, I might use the shell command to output the current count and the results of a test and then split the resulting string. This would be just to avoid another shell call.